# Import xls file and store thedata into database in Django

Tags: django, parsing, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
def contact_list(request):
    importform = ImportExcelForm() 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        importform = ImportExcelForm(request.POST,  request.FILES) 
        if importform.is_valid(): 
            input_excel = request.FILES['input_excel']
            book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=input_excel.read())
            excel_parser= ExcelParser()
            success, log  = excel_parser.read_excel(request.FILES['input_excel'] )  
            return redirect('/member/incident-types/')
    else:
        importform = ImportExcelForm() 
    return render(request, 'incident/contact_list.html',
                  {
                   'about_menu': True,
                   'ImportExcelForm':importform,
                 })
```

forms.py

```
class ImportExcelForm(Form):
    input_excel  = forms.FileField()
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Contacts.objects.all())

def save(self):
    records = xls.reader(self.cleaned_data["input_excel"])
    for line in records:
        input_data = Data()
        input_data.place = self.cleaned_data["user"]
        input_data.name = line[1]
        input_data.number = line[2]
        input_data.save()
```

models.py

```
class Contacts(models.Model):   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    name =  models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    number =  models.IntegerField()
```

This is to import the xls file,read and write the name and contact number in xls file to database field.I am not getting any error in this but it is not parsing the data in database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here. Your form save method (assuming it's indented correctly, which it isn't) iterates over the contents of `self.cleaned_data["input_excel"]`, which is a filename, not a file. But in any case, your view does not call the save method at any point. What it does do is use a completely different set of Excel parsing functions, reads them into a pair of local variables, then does nothing at all with the contents of those variables which go out of scope when the function returns.

I suggest you think about exactly what your logic flow should be, write that down, then write the code to match it.